# How to setup JAAS (in jaas.conf) to use NTLoginModule?

Tags: java, jaas

I guess an example of jaas.conf file that uses the NTLoginModule for authentication would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you mean, but I guess you could have:

```
SomeName
{
   com.sun.security.auth.module.NTLoginModule required;
};
```

and then you can use it:

```
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("SomeName", new SomeCallbackHandler());
lc.login();
```

The `java.security.auth.login.config` property should point to where the config file is located.